# ajax data work and result come to #div1 but in islenendata.php results not appear

Tags: php, ajax

```js
$('.guncel').click(function() {
  var values = [];
  $('.menum').each(function(i, sel) {
    var selectedVal = $(sel).val();
    values.push(selectedVal);
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: 'islenendata.php', // The PHP file that you want to send 
    your user input to
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      data1: values
    }, // The data to be sent
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(result) {
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }
  });
});
```

`welcome.php` ajax data work and result come to `#div1` but in `islenendata.php`

Results not appear this is `islenendata.php` data not appear in this page

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$cars = $_POST['data1'];

$arrlength = count($cars);

for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    echo $cars[$x] ;
    echo "<br>";

}
?>
```

Results are going to `welcome.php` succesful but in `islenendata.php` nothing appear

Comment: Try print_r($cars) and see what comes back.

Comment: if welcome is having the data then your ajax is successful how can you say that no data is in `islenendata.php`?

Comment: print_r($cars) results go to welcome.php but still nothing appear on islenendata.php page